# How to create pandas matrix from one column

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a matrix from one column into two columns, I think this i the right terminology. It's really a 2d matrix I think? I haven't found a lot on this topic which is why I am coming here.

This is what my starting dataframe looks like:

```
df:
[1]
 A
 B
 C
```

This is what I am trying to end up with:

```
df2:
[1]   [2]
 A     B
 A     C  
 B     C 
 B     A 
 C     A 
 C     B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `permutations`

```
from itertools import permutations
df = pd.DataFrame({1:['A','B','C']})
df_out = pd.DataFrame().from_records(permutations(df[1], 2), columns=[1, 2])
print(df_out)
```

OUtput:

```
   1  2
0  A  B
1  A  C
2  B  A
3  B  C
4  C  A
5  C  B
```